# Picture in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have such DialogFragment:

```java
public class GallerySinglePictureDialogFragment extends BasicDialogFragment {
    private Dialog mDialog;
    private Bitmap image;

    public GallerySinglePictureDialogFragment() {
    }

    public GallerySinglePictureDialogFragment(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_GallerySinglePictureDialog);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.frag_gallery_single_picture);
        ((ImageViewTouch)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.image_viewer)).setImageBitmap(image);
        return mDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(getDialog() != null){
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except one thing - when I rotate screen, Bitmap in my dialog fragment disappears.
It is, of course, because of empty class constructor. But I don't know how to fix this bug.

Comment: check this tutorial about using DialogFragment with custom layouts ( including texts and images ) : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/897/using-dialogfragments-android/

Answer (score -1):

Stupid question, sorry.

I replaced

```
private Bitmap image;
```

with

```
private static Bitmap image;
```

And everything, of course, works.

Comment: This may lead to **memory-leaks**. Instead, I would suggest you to recall your image